# Immediate partial results with mysql command line client

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 100 million rows. I want to process one row at a time in no particular order. I don't want to load all the data into memory at once, and I want immediate partial results. To eliminate potential problems with the ORM framework I'm using, I thought I would test my ability to get immediate partial results using the `mysql` command line client, as follows:

```
mysql> select id from my_table \G
```

But the `mysql` client sits there for 75 seconds without printing anything, growing to a final size of 5.8 GB (reported by `top`), and *then* starts printing the results. While printing the results, the memory consumption of the `mysql` client process does not change (it remains at 5.8 GB).

During the first 75 seconds, using a second `mysql` session, I can see that my query is in the `sending data` state. When the client starts printing results, the process command (as reported by `show processlist` changes from `Query` to `Sleep`.

Why does the `mysql` interactive client wait to print results until all the results are in? This is tremendously wasteful of RAM, and fails to yield immediate partial results.

Comment: *Why does the mysql wait to print results until all the results are in?* Because it does not start the next execution step until previous one is finished. This is "by design" and cannot be changed. *But the mysql client sits there for 75 seconds without printing anything, growing to a final size of 5.8 GB* What is the difference between the memory consumption before the query and in memory consumption peak? 5Gb growth seems to be too much for such query. Maybe `id` is GUID?

Comment: Do you want just the ids?  Don't you want the rows?  If so, consider "continuing where you left off".  See [_Pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the MySQL client with the `--quick` option.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_quick

> --quick, -q
>
> Do not cache each query result, print each row as it is received. This
> may slow down the server if the output is suspended. With this option,
> mysql does not use the history file.

The reason the default is to store the result in the client is implied by this documentation. If the interactive client is suspended (for example using Ctrl-Z job control), the MySQL Server must use resources to keep the result set active.

You should consider *not* fetching 100 million rows in a single query to the interactive client.

Comment: Perfect - if I invoke the interactive client with the `--quick` option, then `select id from my_table \G` (and also `select id from my_table;` incidentally) starts printing results immediately, as desired. This is merely a single step in my process of debugging why I'm not getting immediate partial results to the ORM framework I'm using. Thanks for helping me confirm the database is behaving as expected.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between buffered queries and non-buffered queries? That's what the `--quick` option does in the MySQL client.

Comment: Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-use-result.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-store-result.html